# Good ways to log/store results/metrics of reinforcement learning experiments in python?

Tags: python, logging, analytics, reinforcement-learning

I'm currently experimenting with different RL algorithms in environments like the ones in the [OpenAI gym](https://gym.openai.com/envs). Currently I'm just using environments and code I implemented myself because it helps me to understand how things work.

Now I'm looking for a good way to log and store all data created during a course of many episodes.

A few examples:

- states visited
- loss of my neural network
- number of steps/episode
- reward per episide

I thought about using the python logging module although it's probably intended for a different use. Also I thought about using the observer pattern to push events (agent takes action, newstate, end of episode etc.) to different loggers I'm attaching as observers.

Are there better ways to realize this functionality?
Or maybe there is some good example code I can learn from?

Is using the logging module a good idea? I thought it could be beneficial because I could control what's logged or turning logging on or off. But if I'm using the observer pattern I don't really need this.

Sincerely
David

Answer (score 1):

Most people implement this from scratch for their experiments according to their needs. You may want to reference the way [BURLAP](http://burlap.cs.brown.edu/), a popular Java RL library, structures its plotting (it doesn't do logging, but the same information is required in either case). The example experimenter setup is [here](https://github.com/jmacglashan/burlap/blob/e69b9ef937f92f14de4744b0e8dbfceadd599c23/src/main/java/burlap/behavior/singleagent/auxiliary/performance/LearningAlgorithmExperimenter.java).

Typically, I whip up a class that allows me to quickly take means/confidences of some sequence of observations, whether that's episode reward or evaluation steps, etc.

```
from typing import List

import numpy as np
import scipy as scipy
import scipy.stats


class ExperimentLog():
    def __init__(self, series: List[float], signfigance_level: float):
        self.means = []
        self.variances = []
        self.confidences = []
        self.n = 1
        self.current_observation_num = 0
        self.series = series
        self.signfigance_level = signfigance_level

    def observe(self, value: float):
        mean = None
        variance = None
        if self.current_observation_num > len(self.means) - 1:
            self.means.append(0.0)
            self.variances.append(0.0)
            mean = 0.0
            variance = 0.0
        else:
            mean = self.means[self.current_observation_num]
            variance = self.variances[self.current_observation_num]

        delta = value - mean
        mean += delta / self.n
        variance += delta * (value - mean)

        self.means[self.current_observation_num] = mean
        self.variances[self.current_observation_num] = variance
        self.current_observation_num += 1

    def finalize_confidences(self):
        assert self.n > 1
        self.variances = [variance / (self.n - 1) for variance in
                          self.variances]

        for (mean, variance) in zip(self.means, self.variances):
            crit = scipy.stats.t.ppf(1.0 - self.signfigance_level, self.n - 1)
            width = crit * np.math.sqrt(variance) / np.math.sqrt(self.n)
            self.confidences.append(width)

    def observe_trial_end(self):
        self.n += 1
        self.current_observation_num = 0
```

I populate it directly in the learning or evaluation loop. Then it's simple to save this to a file:

```
def save(name, log: ExperimentLog, out_dir: str, unique_num: int = 0):

    out_prefix = out_dir

    if not os.path.exists(out_prefix):
        os.makedirs(out_prefix)
    filename = str(experiment_num) + "_" + str(num_trials) + "_" + name + str(unique_num) + ".csv"
    full_out_path = os.path.join(out_prefix, filename)
    if log.n > 1:
        log.finalize_confidences()
        data = np.c_[(log.series, log.means, log.variances, log.confidences)]
    else:
        data = np.c_[(log.series, log.means)]
    np.savetxt(full_out_path, data,
               fmt=["%d", "%f", "%f", "%f"],
               delimiter=",")
```